# Как правильно написать SQL запрос?

Tags: php, sql

Есть таблица `users` в которой есть `id` и `username` и есть таблица `user_message`, в которой есть :

> - id
> - id_from
> - id_for
> - message

Так вот, как сделать запрос, чтобы он брал `id_from`, `id_for`, сравнивал с `id`, который в таблице `users` и возвращал `username`.

Это нужно для того, чтобы в чат выводились вместо `id` имена пользователей.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно поступить следующим образом

```
SELECT
  m.message AS message,
  fu.username AS from_username,
  tu.username AS for_username
FROM
  user_message AS m
LEFT JOIN
  username AS fu
ON
  m.id_from = fu.id
LEFT JOIN
  username AS tu
ON
  m.id_for = tu.id
```

Comment: А что означают m.   fu.   tu..   ?

Comment: Это алиасы для имен таблиц, в случае user_message можно обойтись без них, а вот в случае двух таблиц username, которые JOIN-нятся ниже уже не получится, так как у нас две таблицы с одним и тем же именем. Их волей не волей приходится переименовывать при помощи ключевого слова AS и потом ссылаться на алиасы.

Comment: username только в таблице users, в моем случае же нету повторяющихся таблиц?

Comment: Да, но в таблице message, у вас два ключа: id_from и id_for. Я так понимаю, оба они связаны с таблицей username и для обоих из них нужно извлечь имя? Вам придется два раза обратиться к таблице username, воспользуетесь вы мои вариантом или реализуете его через вложенные запросы.

Answer (score 0):

Если есть 2 таблицы users в которой id|username|usermessage и таблица messages id|id_form|id_for|message  то типа такого

> SELECT id, username FROM users WHERE (SELECT messages.id_from, messages.id_for FROM
>   messages WHERE messages.id_from = users.id AND messages.id_for =
>   users.id )